# Forward an Issue to the concern person

Tags: professionalism, communication, work-environment, conflict-resolution, email-etiquette

The business people sent a mail to us that "The application is failing frequently with same error". They want to us to look into the issue,but we are not the right person. How do we forward this issue to the concern person and also we have to inform the Business team that going forward you have to reach out that concern person for the below issue.

suggest some professional content for the above.

Comment: Follow the procedure or policy established by your company.

Comment: I guess there's not really such a thing as too simple of a question, but to me all this calls for is hitting "Forward" to the right team and CCing the original sender with a comment "It's actually team X that's responsible." Is that basically what you're asking for or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

Forward the email to the appropriate party, and include the sender on the Cc list.

The email should say:

> Hello name.
>
> Thank you for contacting my team about the problem in XXXXXX.
>
> YYYYYY team is responsible for handling problem-reports and inquiries such as yours. I am forwarding your message to PPPPPP in that team.
>
> If there's anything else I can do to help you, please don't hesitate to get in touch.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> BharaniRaj

The elements of email etiquette here:

1. Greet the sender by name.
2. Show that you looked at the message enough to determine XXXXX, what it's about.
3. Give the name of the team and person to whom you forwarded the message.
4. Offer to help the person with any **other** issues they may have. As Joe mentioned, they'll get the hint after a few (dozen ;-) tries.

You can probably put together a quick template for this in a text file so you don't have to rewrite it every time you need it.

Comment: Thank you Jones. It really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 6):

> How do we forward this issue to the concern person and also we have to
>   inform the Business team that going forward you have to reach out that
>   concern person for the below issue.

Simply forward the email to the correct person, and CC the Business Team.

Write something like "I'm forwarding your request to [name of correct person]. They should be able to help you."

They'll get the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are forwarding it to the correct person. If you don't know the correct person, or the correct email address, then respond back to the sender with what you know. Sometimes you will get an email where your name was accidentally picked, and you have no idea where it should go.

Don't start an email storm by replying all. It is possible that you were accidentally added, and the other 10 people on the email already know what to do.

If you do know where to send it, include the sender and the new person on the email so they can know about the email, and the sender can add them to the conversation.